# Given $100$ coplanar points, no $3$ collinear, then at most $70$ percent triangles formed using these points are acute-angled

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

> (IMO-$1970$) Given $100$ coplanar points, no $3$ collinear, prove that at most $70$ percent of the triangles formed using these points are acute-angled.

I know that one solution proceeds by showing that given $5$ points, at least $3$ triangles are non-acute-angled. This can be used quite easily to prove the statement in the problem. A solution can be found [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1970_IMO_Problems/Problem_6) .

However, I am interested in an approach that uses Turan's theorem or Zarankiewicz's lemma. For those of who haven't heard of this lemma, the lemma states that if a graph with $n$ vertices has no $K_k$ as subgraph (i.e. it is k-clique free), then there is a vertex with degree at most $\lfloor \dfrac{k-2}{k-1}n\rfloor$.

The reason I ask this question is because the following problem has a solution using Turan's theorem/ Zarankiewicz's lemma.

> Consider $21$ points on a circle. Show that at least $100$ pairs of points subtend an angle less than or equal to $120$ degree at the centre.

The solution to this problem proceeds by considering the graph with the points as vertices and the edge between two vertices indicate that the two vertices subtend an angle larger than $120$ degree at the centre. It is now fairly easy to see that the graph is triangle free. Now just use Turan's theorem.

While my problem isn't the same as the one I have just shown, they both seem to have some sort of connection (they are both extremal graph theory problems).

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Btw, I don't expect there to be an answer to this question.

Comment: The link to IMO 1970: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1970_IMO_Problems/Problem_6

Comment: We were given this question as part of the coaching for IMO 1978 (I failed to make the team). I managed to get it down to about 67%. I will post more about this when I have the time.

Comment: It is actually enough to check it for $4$ points and then prove the obvious double-counting inequality to go from $n$ to $n+1$. No need to to $n=5$ with case by case analysis.

Comment: @TonyK I found that you have sketched your solution method [in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593367/49227). It is a very nice idea!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many acute triangles can be formed by 100 points in a plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592964/how-many-acute-triangles-can-be-formed-by-100-points-in-a-plane)